# Passing Data From Ajax Call to C# Web Method

Tags: c#, ajax, web, methods

We would like to send the contents of a web form with ajax call to a web method, which in turn calls a web service to insert the form contents to the database. 
We do not use MVC, but use our custom c# code.

Our javascript is as folllows:

```
        var data = {
            HT: $("input[name='HT']").val(),
            KT: $("input[name='KT']").val(),
            T: $("input[name='T']").val()
        };
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "LTCreate.aspx/Create",
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            dataType: "json",
            data: JSON.stringify(data),
            async: true,
            success: function(msg) {
                alert(msg.d);
            }
        });
```

Our c# code is as follows:

```
        [WebMethod(EnableSession = true)]
        public static string Create(string strJson)
        {             


                 HT = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<pb.CLS_HT>(strJson);

         ret = ws.INSERT_HT(SYSTEM_CODE, USER_INFO, HT, ref errMsg);
         if (ret < 0)
         {
             return ret.ToString() + " " + errMsg;
         }
         else
         {
             return ret.ToString();
         }
       }
```

When i run the above code, we get the following error message:

> Message: "Invalid web service call, missing value for parameter:
>   'strJson'.",… Stack Trace:  at
>   System.Web.Script.Services.WebServiceMethodData.CallMethod(Object
>   target, IDictionary`2 parameters) ↵   at
>   System.Web.Script.Services.RestHandler.InvokeMethod

How could we properly get the contents of data string in c# web method?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Use ScriptManager and Enable PageMethods like this :

```
<asp:ScriptManager ID="ScriptManager1" EnablePageMethods="true" runat="server"></asp:ScriptManager>
```

Write Function like this :

```
[System.Web.Services.WebMethod(EnableSession = true)]
    public static string Edit_Program(string ProgramID)
    {
        //Some Codes
        return "OK";

    }
```

Call Function from JavaScript :

```
function Edit_Program(data) {
    PageMethods.Edit_Program(data, OnSuccessEditCallback, OnFailureCallback);
    }

    function OnSuccessCallback(res) {
        //Some Codes
    }

    function OnSuccessEditCallback(res) {
        //Some Codes
    }
```